# AngularFire pushing to array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm developing a contact book application that can have groups with members in them. A member has a name, title, and email but that is not important. I have following controller that has an `array` of all groups, and an index of which group I'm currently dealing with. Also, there is a function that is supposed to add a member to a specific group like below:

```
   groupControllers.controller('MemberGroupController', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$routeParams', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $routeParams, $location, $routeParams) {
        $scope.groups = $firebaseArray(ref);
        $scope.whichGroup =  $routeParams.groupId;
        this.addToGroup = function(member){
            $scope.groups[$scope.whichGroup].members.push(member);
            $scope.groups[$scope.whichGroup].members.$save();
        };
    }]);
```

I know the addToGroup function is getting the member because it logs the correct member to the console. For some reason when I do this it doesn't actually add the member to `firebase`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to call `$save` on `$firebaseObject` instances. In fact the call to `$save` might well break things, since it triggers a potential race condition between the `push` and the `$save`.

### Update

This will work:

```
groupControllers.controller('MemberGroupController', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$routeParams', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $routeParams, $location, $routeParams) {
    $scope.groups = $firebaseArray(ref);
    $scope.whichGroup =  $routeParams.groupId;
    this.addToGroup = function(member){
        ref.child('groups').child($scope.whichGroup).child('members').push(member);
    };
}]);
```

### Avoid building nests

Note that you seem to be building a so-called "nest", a hierarchy that seems intuitive, but will limit you down the line. Read the section of the [Firebase documentation on structuring data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-denormalizing-data) to learn more about this.

Consider splitting up the group's members from its other metadata:

```
groups
  -Jy32724372
    name: "Group 1"
  -Jy46728671 
    name: "Group 2"
groups_members:
  -Jy32724372
    twitter:3247423678
    email:23478101
    anonymous:23054389
  -Jy46728671 
    email:23478101
    anonymous:45764357
```

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful, but doesn't solve the current problem. Is there a verison of $save for arrays?

Comment: Thanks! That almost works but I'm getting

Error: Firebase.push failed: first argument  contains an invalid key ($id) in property 'groups.JsW25ppMJYYkAezZzyJ.members.asdf'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

Answer (score 0):

Call the $save method on firebase object to push local changes to firebase. Have a look on the following AngularFire $save guide:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-objects.html#section-api-summary

Checkout the $save method guide. Hope, it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks! But I'm using FirebaseArray, and as the guy above said, $save doesn't really work for arrays.

Comment: You can convert array to Objects, before calling the $save function on firebase object and pass in the object as required by the function.

Comment: Got it!!! In case of firebaseArray, you can use $add method applicable on firebaseArrays. Have a look on following guide on firebase arrays:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html

Comment: When using $add I get that $add is not a function. Since the members array is inside the firebasearray of Groups, can I not call .$add on it?

Comment: No, you will not be able to call the $add method on any property of the array. You need to call it on returned array of firebaseArray function. In your case, you can call it like:

 $scope.groups.$add(param);

where param, while be your new member to be inserted.

Comment: Yeah but that would add another group, not a member to the group.

I'm trying to $scope.groups.members.$add(param) but that is resulting in $add is not a function

Comment: You are trying to update pre-exiting member in array, rather than saving a new member. In that case, you need to first fetch that particular member of array, then update data and finally call the save method  on array. 
`Example: 
var item = messages.$getRecord(someRecordKey);
item.user = "alanisawesome";
messages.$save(item).then(function() {
  // data has been saved to our Firebase database
});`

[link](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html#section-modifying-the-array)
checkout the update code block